# What can we do if some site copies our content?

Tags: discussion, site-policies, plagiarism

Currently I am seeing plagiarized questions posted on Quora. For example [this one on Quora](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/The-Elder-Scrolls-V-Can-you-give-the-naked-stalking-courier-his-clothes-back) was posted from [Can I give the naked stalking courier his clothes back?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37670/can-i-give-the-naked-stalking-courier-his-clothes-back).

This was just one example I am reporting. But this has been happening more frequently since Quora instituted their Partner program, where you get paid to ask questions.

Is there anything we can do when we run across such examples?

Comment: Somebody's scraping page titles.  For proper usage, attribution is required, but beyond reporting, there isn't much else that needs to be done.  SE can handle it from there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If Quora wants to pay for that kind of low-effort content, they're free to do that. They seem to only use the title, which isn't really enough in my opinion to make it plagiarism. There are only so many different ways you can formulate the same question.

Copying a full question or answer is something different, but only the title isn't something I'd spend any effort of fighting. I'd just wait until Quora runs out of VC money and shuts down.